# How to Convert bytes Base64 to the equivalent file then download to my Device Swift

Tags: swift

```
let object = fileArray[index.row] as! [String:Any]
let name = object["filename"] as! String
let data = NSData(base64Encoded: object["content"] as! String, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) as Data?
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [data!.write(withName: name)], applicationActivities: nil)
self.present(activityController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Here is my code. but unfortunately it saves a file with file url path and not my expected file.

Comment: Besides many issues you have in your code the main one is that you should first write the data to disk then use the file url of that file when creating the activity controller

Comment: Noted on this. I will try it. thanks

Comment: try `if let object = fileArray[index.row] as? [String:Any], let name = object["filename"] as? String, let base64Encoded = object["content"] as? String, let data = Data(base64Encoded: base64Encoded, options: .ignoreUnknownCharacters) {` `let fileURL = FileManager.default.temporaryDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)` `do {` `try data.write(to: fileURL)` `let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL], applicationActivities: nil)` `self.present(activityController, animated: true)` `} catch {` `print(error)` `}` `}`